# virtual hosts always opend as localhost

Tags: apache, virtualhost, document-root

I try to set up a virtual host on my ubuntu system. But it always opens the default DocumentRoot instead of the declared root.

/etc/apache2/sites-available/falkdev.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *>

    ServerName falk.dev

    ServerAdmin mail@falk-roeder.de
    DocumentRoot "/home/falk/Arbeit/senseless/operativ/"
#   DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory "/home/falk/Arbeit/senseless/operativ/">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>



    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       Thinki
127.0.0.1       falk.dev
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

If I now call falk.dev then its directing to /var/www/ instead /home/falk/Arbeit/senseless/operativ. Whats wrong?

And I can call now sd.dev or foo.dev and always coming to /var/www/.

I also have phpStorm running, and it opens successfull pages with the builtinserver on localhost:63342

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the default seciotn in apache2.conf and adapt the path there to my new path. Also i dissabled the 000-default.conf by

> a2dissite 000-default.conf

After that I had to reload apache.